# Rename Git branch folder

Tags: git, version-control

I have a Git repository with a remote branch structure like this:

```
bugfix001 
bugfix002     
feature
    feature001
    feature002
    feature003
master
task
    task001
    task002
```

where 'feature' and 'task' are folders within the branch structure and the 'feature001', 'feature002' branches are under the parent 'feature' branch folder.

My question is - is it possible to rename the 'feature' parent folder and keep all the branches under it. So I could rename it to 'hamster' and the structure would look like this

```
hamster
    feature001
    feature002
    feature003
```

Just to be clear, I'm not referring to the local file structure, this is the branch structure on the remote. To add a branch under the 'feature' folder I would use:

```
git checkout -b feature/feature004
```

I realise that I can rename each sub branch individually and push to the remote but can I rename the 'feature' parent folder which will cause will the sub branches follow the new name?

Comment: Your best bet is to rename the branches one at a time, using a shell script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as "branch folders" in git.

You only have named branches, and the names you are using happen to include a slash, which reminds the humans of a folder-structure; but it really could be something else as well (e.g. `@`).

To conclude: you will have to rename every branch, and push the new branch names (and delete the old ones)

But that should be simple enough:

```
remote=origin
for branch in $(git branch --list "feature/*")
do
 newbranch="hamster/${branch#feature/}"
 # locally create new branch based on old one
 git checkout "${branch}"
 git checkout -b "${newbranch}"
 # push the new branch to the remote
 git push --set-upstream "${remote}" "${newbranch}"
 # delete old branch remotely and locally
 git push "${remote}" ":${branch}"
 git branch -d "${branch}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

As the others have posted, there's no folder concept in Git, these are just names. Your only choice is to rename them one by one. A script can help with doing this - here's an example for renaming the local branches:

```
for i in $(git branch --list 'feature/*') ; do
    echo "$i"
    # Cut off the first part
    newbranch=new/$(basename "$i")

    # Rename the existing branch
    git branch -m "$i" "$newbranch"

    # Push the new branche
    git push origin "$newbranch"

    # Delete the old branch from the remote
    git push origin :"$newbranch"
done
```

This will rename all branches matching 'feature/*' to 'new/*'.

Anybody pulling from this repo will have to set up tracking for the renamed branches, as the previous branches will no longer be there.

Comment: nice trick using `basename` to strip of the path-like component; it might not do what you expect if you have tags with multiple slashes: `/feature/gui/foo` and `feature/network/foo` will both be renamed to `new/foo`

Comment: That's true - it will only leave the last part intact.

Answer (score 2):

When you name branches with a `/` in the name, then a directory is created in `refs/heads`.  For example a branch named `feature/feature001` creates a directory named `refs/heads/feature/` which contains a file `feature001`.  If you rename the `feature` directory, you are, in effect, renaming every branch that started with `feature/` (modulo anything you have in `packed-refs`).  This isn't the recommended way to rename branches, but it does work.  You will need to edit your config file to reconnect any of those branches that specified a tracking branch.  Other than that, and again ignoring anything that might be in `packed-refs`, you can do what you are asking.

Comment: That's interesting but sounds pretty scary

Answer (score 1):

in git, you can name a branch in the way you want, using slashes (`/`) or not. These slashes **DO NOT** refer to folder separations. So if you want to rename all branches starting with "feature", you'll have to do it manually for each of them.

Using the same prefix can help you to list certain subsets of branches; like this:

```
git branch --list "feature/*"
```

but not much more than that afaik.