# Renaming remote branch on git and update log

Tags: git, branch, rename

So the title says it pretty much all. I found an old answer on how to rename remote tags ([Rename Git branch folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458667/rename-git-branch-folder)) but I am worrying my log is going to make no sense after the changes (eg. Is it going to report an inexistent branch merge onto develop?).

Is this going to be the case or does git pickup the changes and changes the entries of `git log`?

Also will my tags keep pointing at the right locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming branches is not an operation available in git. What you're actually doing is creating new branches and deleting old one. By creating a new branch with the same history of an existing branch, you're simply creating a reference to a commit. Therefore, you are not changing all commits (changing a commit message changes a commit).

So if you git checkout and git push, all previous commits will have messages referencing branches that may or may not exist anymore. This is *normal* and you don't need to worry about it.

And since your commits won't be changing, your tags will all be unchanged and totally fine.

Comment: sounds safe to me! I will proceed! Thanks

Comment: btw is the solution I linked the "right" one for "renaming" branches?

Comment: Yes, you create new branch with git checkout (setting the appropriate start_point) then you push the new branch to you upstream (and set the upstream in the config with --set-upstream) then you delete the old branch from the upstream with a git push <remote> :<branchname-to-delete>

Comment: so is the following only renaming localy and linking to the old remote branch?
`git checkout oldbranch`

`git branch -m oldbranch newbranch`

`git push origin newbranch`

Comment: Yes, -m renames the branch and maintains the configured upstream remote branch